# How to send custom title and link in php with onesignal

Tags: php, push-notification, onesignal

So i finally get one signal to send push notification to specific users users php.
My problem is that i want to include unique title and link in the php script so when user received the notifcation they can see the custom title instead of the website title and when click it takes them to that specific page of the website. here is my code.

`$content = array(
            "en" => "custom message to users",
            );

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "App Id",
        'include_player_ids' => array($playerId),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );`
```

Comment: Never mind guys I figure it out

Answer (score 4):

I figure it out. 
What i did was to store the users player id in the database then call the push message function which includes the query to get the specific player id of the user i want to send the push message to then include the player id as objects works perfect. Here is my code incased someone else need this.

```
$content = array(
        "en" => $pushMsg,
    );

    $headings = array(
        "en" => "Fimibucks Marketplace",
    );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "app_id",
        'include_player_ids' => array($playerId), // Play id from database
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'headings' => $headings,//Title of your website
        'contents' => $content, // the message
        'url' => $urls // url of the page you want to send the user to after clicking the notification.
    );
```